# Bivariate problem, what is the best model for this? Scoring probability depending on distance

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, binomial-distribution

I have been directed here from the main stackoverflow site, where i described my problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218132/statistics-and-r-ideas-on-how-to-find-a-fitting-model-shot-result-depending-on).

Basically i have a set of sports data containing shots with their distance to the goal and the result (make / miss). I would like to verify two hypotheses:
h1: the probability of scoring is monotonously falling with increasing distance
h2: the function best suited to approximate this is nonlinear (i expect the loss of accuracy to be much higher when stepping from 0 to 1 foot than it is from 50 to 51).

Beyond proving h1 and h2 i would like to generate a plot with the probability of scoring relative to the distance. I have five seasons of approx. 80k shots each so there should be sufficient data. What i would like to plot i guess is the mean of each discrete distance (in ft, in this case) and then a distribution / function that approximates the resulting graph if those means were connected.

I am working on a paper and i use R as the tool of choice.

I've tried a linear model which yields very poor results in terms of R^2. One contributor suggested a logit model because of the 1/0 nature of the dependant variable but i still struggle to prove my hypotheses based on the rather abstract result of logit.

How would you go about this? How to find the best fitting model for this situation? How to plot the "1"'s only in a intuitive way, ideally in R?

THanks everyone in advance and apologies if this question is too "basic".

Comment: If you expect the relationship to be non-linear then fitting a linear model (or a linear logistic model) is unlikely to be helpful. You need some non-linear functions of distance in your model.

Comment: Thank you. I asked because i am aware lm and glm are not the best fit here, i am just too new to this to know how to proceed - my class mostly taught OLS.

Comment: If you just want a plot have you thought of a loess plot?

Comment: THank you, i have not - i will look into it. The two hypotheses i would like to prove (even though obvious) are the negative Relation (h1) and it being stronger than linear (h2), but a good plot would be a great beginning. Your time and help very much apprechiated.